# Is it necessary to block the assignment operator and the copy constructor when using smart pointers?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, copy-constructor

I've seen in several places the advice to either define your own assignment operator/copy constructor, or to block the default ones by declaring them private.

However, the only danger I've been able to find was the problem of creating copies of pointers that could be dangling pointers later.

In modern C++ pointers are rare, and most classes just use smart pointers (e.g. from boost or from the std library in C++11). Is it still necessary to declare the assignment operator and the copy constructor for classes that have no raw pointers?

And mainly: What are the dangers of not doing that? What kind of unexpected behavior can occur?

Comment: The only time you need to define your own assignment operator or copy constructor is at the same time you define a destructor. This is the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). But if you're only using resource managing classes and not creating one, there should be no need to do anything special, because the implicitly generated special functions for your class will use the specifically written ones from the resource managing classes, which should just do the Right Thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in the question [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Also there is a very good explanation on the following website:

> [Can I trust the Compiler-Generated Copy Constructor and Assignment Operator?](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=368)
>
> Compiler-generated code is your best friend, provided that
>   you adhere to good style OO practices and know the rules. As explained
>   in part I, the compiler- generated copy constructor and assignment
>   operator perform member-wise copying of user-declared data members. By
>   replacing low-level datatypes -- raw pointers and char arrays for
>   instance -- with their high-level Standard Library counterparts
>   std::tr1::shared_ptr and std::string, not only are you eliminating the
>   onerous bugs associated with manual resource management, you’re also
>   guaranteeing that the compiler-generated copy constructor and
>   assignment operator will do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not it's not necessary to hide those operators. `std::unique_ptr` already is noncopyable(you can only move it). And other kinds - `std::shared_ptr` will increment internal ref count, `std::weak_ptr` will do nothing since it has `lock` method. You can read more [here (Boost libs)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)

Comment: Incrementing internal ref count is not necessary what you want of your application and may have logical consequences

Comment: You can forget to reset those pointers in time to free memory they owns.

Answer (score -1):

The danger with not defining your own assignment operator/copy/move constructor is the possibility of unexpected behavior. These operations are very easily invoked without you being aware of that, causing the unexpected behavior. Declaring them as private will result in compilation error on such occasions.

Also note that not everywhere smart pointers are used. There are more restricted environments (such as kernel, embedded etc.) that generally won't have STL or boost.

Comment: The question is thus: What kind of unexpected behavior can be dangerous for the application?

Comment: Any unexpected behavior can be dangerous because, well, it's unexpected...